# how to load cells without affecting the first cell of the table view in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am new to ios developments but I am doing something like this : I have a table view and I implemented show a date picker, when the first cell of the table view is clicked [date picker will show below the first cell]. so now I want to reload cells according to the date selected from the date picker but whole table view should not reloaded because the first cell which is allow to show a date picker should be there always.

So I want to load cells with some data without affecting the first cell. How can I do this. I have an idea like this :

if I can identify the remaining cells except the first cell then I can use a if condition in my `cellForRowAtIndexpath` method but I don't know how to identify remaining cells..please someone help me. I will put my codes below..

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {


    UITableViewCell *cell;

    NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    // display in 12HR/24HR (i.e. 11:25PM or 23:25) format according to User Settings
    [dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
    NSString *currentTime = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:today];
    NSDate *date=[dateFormatter dateFromString:currentTime];



    if(indexPath.row==0){
        VCPerson *person = self.persons[indexPath.row];

        cell = [self createPersonCell:person];

    }

    else if ([self datePickerIsShown] && (self.datePickerIndexPath.row == indexPath.row)){

        // VCPerson *person = self.persons[indexPath.row -1];



        cell = [self createPickerCell:date];

    }




    if(indexPath.section!=0 && tapfirstCell) {

        UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell*)[self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kOtherCellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
        //cell.delegate_Dtepick = self;
        NSDictionary *dictionary = [_dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
        NSArray *array = [dictionary objectForKey:@"data"];
        NSString *cellValue = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.textLabel.text =cellValue;

    }

    return cell;




   /*
    if ([self datePickerIsShown] && (self.datePickerIndexPath.row == indexPath.row)){

        // VCPerson *person = self.persons[indexPath.row -1];



        cell = [self createPickerCell:date];

    }



    else {

       // cellForDatePickCell* cell;
        VCPerson *person = self.persons[indexPath.row];

        cell = [self createPersonCell:person];
        //cell = [self createCustomCell:indexPath];
    }

    return cell;


 */




  }
```

in my code it doesn't show the remaining cells after first cell as I wanted. Please someone help me.

**EDIT :**
Here is my entire class

http://pastie.org/8993858

**EDIT 2 :**

here is an illustration of what i need to do..

[image]

Comment: can you show more code? For example, the `- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {` as it determines how many cells to create.

Comment: What happened if the condition fails?
`if ([self datePickerIsShown] && (self.datePickerIndexPath.row == indexPath.row))`

Comment: then the date picker will not show below the first cell

Answer (score 2):

Your DatePicker should be in HeaderView not in TableViewCell.

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if (headerView == nil) 
        headerView = [[[HeaderView alloc] init] autorelease]; // further customizations
    return headerView;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 30.0;
}
```

Create headerView containing DatePicker or any View you want to add to your HeaderView. On reloading tableView you can simply return headerView which is already created, and updating all viewAtRows according to your needs. [This](http://www.accella.net/custom-header-and-footer-views-for-uitableviews/) tutorial can help you regarding how to customize HeaderView.

Comment: thank you .. i think this will help me.. i will try and let you know :)

Comment: here i have a quiestion @Faisal in my case, when i touch the first cell then a date picker slide down below the cell. can i do the same thing in headerView ?

Comment: i am talking about something like this :  http://masteringios.com/blog/2013/10/31/ios-7-in-line-uidatepicker/

Comment: I am not getting what you want... Can you attach some kind of illustration what you want. It can be so useful.

Comment: i have re edit my post... as you can see in the third picture[right most one] it has different cell layout and also the date picking cell.. i want to do like that here...please give me instructions...

Comment: It can be more user friendly if you put your DatePicker in ActionSheet like described in this http://mkonstantinou.blogspot.com/2012/12/adding-done-button-to-uidatepicker.html

Answer (score 0):

I've just have an idea. You should delete the picker row, then insert the rows you want. Using two methods below to achieve that:

Firstly, call `[self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPath withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimation]` to delete the picker row, obviously.

Then after that call `[self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPath withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimation]`, to let the table knows about that.

Of course, that's not all the work, you have to handle the UITableView data source properly to conform that situation (numberOfRowsAtIndexPath,cellForRowAtIndexPath... should return appropriate results).

All in here: [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/deleteRowsAtIndexPaths%3awithRowAnimation%3a)

Comment: actually up to now.. i could implement the date picker feature successfully...but when the date is selected i want to reload the cells.. but also the picker cell also should be there as i showed in my post..i think the solution which you given here, remove the picker cell and will load other cells..but i want picker cell also with other cells

Comment: @Darshana: So you don't remove the date picker cell, just insert new row. :)