# Inline date picker crashed on second attempt

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, tableview

I have been struggling for this issue for two week now. but by the help of StackOverflow people I have came up with 95% successful implementation..

[Here is my problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22861205/how-to-load-cells-without-affecting-the-first-cell-of-the-table-view-in-ios).. and now I could load my results with the picker cell [First most cell] when the date is selected.

Now I have another issue...when i run my application at first time, it is works as I expected..but when i tap the first most cell to pick a different date  , then the application crashed..

[Here](http://pastie.org/9003079) is the log output...

below is my codes for the implementation

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section             {

 NSDictionary* reqFdate= [ScheduleView getRequestForDate];

if (reqFdate.count == 0) {
    NSInteger numberOfRows = [self.persons count];

    if ([self datePickerIsShown]){

        numberOfRows++;

    }

    return numberOfRows;
}
else{

    return reqFdate.count + 1;
}

}




  - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
  {


    UITableViewCell *cell;

    NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    // display in 12HR/24HR (i.e. 11:25PM or 23:25) format according to User Settings
    [dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
    NSString *currentTime = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:today];
    NSDate *date=[dateFormatter dateFromString:currentTime];



    if(indexPath.row==0){
        VCPerson *person = self.persons[0];

        cell = [self createPersonCell:person];

    }



    else if ([self datePickerIsShown] && (self.datePickerIndexPath.row == 1)){

        // VCPerson *person = self.persons[indexPath.row -1];



        cell = [self createPickerCell:date];

    }

    else{

        cellForDatePickCell *cell = (cellForDatePickCell*)[self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kOtherCellIdentifier];
        cell.delegate_Dtepick = self;

        return cell;

    }


    if(indexPath.section!=0 && tapfirstCell) {

        UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell*)[self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kOtherCellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
        //cell.delegate_Dtepick = self;
        NSDictionary *dictionary = [_dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
        NSArray *array = [dictionary objectForKey:@"data"];
        NSString *cellValue = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.textLabel.text =cellValue;

    }

    return cell;



}


-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {




[self.tableView beginUpdates];

if ([self datePickerIsShown] && (self.datePickerIndexPath.row - 1 == indexPath.row)){

    [self hideExistingPicker];
   // [self.tableView reloadData];
    //[self viewDidLoad];



    //call the service and take the results





    NSString* selecteDate = [ScheduleView getDate];

    NSString* prsonID =[LoginView getPersonID];

    NSDictionary* parms = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:prsonID,@"caregiverPersonId",selecteDate,@"selectedDate", nil];

    jsonpaser* jp = [[jsonpaser alloc]init];

    [jp getWebServiceResponce:@"http://qa.vardle.com/Mobile/WebServices/AppointmentService.asmx/GetAppointments" :parms success:^(NSDictionary *responseObject)
     {



         requestsF_date = responseObject;
         NSLog(@"RESPONSEFORDATE_IN DIDSELECT :%@",requestsF_date);
         NSArray* indexpaths = [self getIndexPaths];
         NSLog(@"indexPATHS %@",indexpaths);
         [self.tableView reloadData];

     }];






    // cellForDatePickCell *cell = (cellForDatePickCell*)[self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kOtherCellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    // cell.delegate_Dtepick = self;
    //tapfirstCell = true;
   /*
   cellForDatePickCell *cell=(cellForDatePickCell*)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    if(![cell.textLabel.text isEqualToString:@"5/23/14"])
    {
        return; 
    }
  */


    if (tapfirstCell==false) {
        tapfirstCell = true;
    }
    else{
        tapfirstCell = false;
    }




}else {

    NSIndexPath *newPickerIndexPath = [self calculateIndexPathForNewPicker:indexPath];

    if ([self datePickerIsShown]){

        [self hideExistingPicker];



    }

    [self showNewPickerAtIndex:newPickerIndexPath];

    self.datePickerIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:newPickerIndexPath.row + 1 inSection:0];

}

[self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

[self.tableView endUpdates];
```

}

please someone tell me where is the issue..why app is crashed when i try to pick a date second time..

please help

Comment: that crashed bcz you are trying to insert or delete some index that actually not in to array or that particular place from that you are trying to remove. check with NSlog how much value in to your array and which index actually there and which one are you trying to remove or add.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have fix my issue... i didnt deleted the rows before i start to show the date picker again..

[here is the full code](http://pastebin.com/XUQxD4yV)

here what i did was : i use Inline Datepicker with the table view [date picker will show by selecting the first cell of the table view].according to the date selected from the picker, i am displaying my custom cells below the first cell.[because the first cell always there to pick a date from a date picker].

if someone want to do the same thing which i did i think my code will help you

thank you